# Adding Numbers to ol li via counters (when using display flex) not working

Tags: html, css, css-counter

Add numbers to the following list using `CSS: Counters`. I am trying, but I think I am not applying currently.

```css
#two li {display: flex;}
li::before {counter-increment: all};
```

```html
<div>
<ol>
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Mango</li>
  <li>Oranges</li>
  <li>Peach</li>
  <li>PineApplie</li>
</ol>
</div>

<div>
<ol id="two">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Mango</li>
  <li>Oranges</li>
  <li>Peach</li>
  <li>PineApplie</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Please, help. I need same numbering in second-list also, where due to some reason, I have to use `display:flex` on lis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to reset the counter in `body` tag `body { counter-reset: all; }`

```css
body {
  counter-reset: all;
}
#two li {display: flex;}
#two li::before {
  counter-increment: all;
  content: "list " counter(all) "- ";
}
```

```html
<div>
<ol>
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Mango</li>
  <li>Oranges</li>
  <li>Peach</li>
  <li>PineApplie</li>
</ol>
</div>

<div>
<ul id="two">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Mango</li>
  <li>Oranges</li>
  <li>Peach</li>
  <li>PineApplie</li>
</ul>
</div>
```